# replace one character in a string with 2

Tags: java, string, replace

I am having a problem with my code and wanted to ask you guru's a quick question.. My program takes lines out of a text file and saves them to a string and modifies it.. I'm doing a little test to see how to replace characters in those saved strings. I'm using `replace` but it seems like I can't replace one character with 2 or vice-versa...

```
import java.io.*;

public class chracreplace {

 public static void main(String args[]){
  String Str1 = new String("AMC0006RV55555");
  String Str2 = new String("RVBMCLTWD12345");

  System.out.print("Possible Word:" );
  System.out.println(Str1.replace('5', '6'));

  System.out.print("Possible Word: :" );
  System.out.println(Str2.replace('R' + 'V', 'n'));

 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write

```
'R' + 'V'
```

That results an `int` of adding char's ascii codes and replacable must be a String as well.

What you are looking for is

```
System.out.println(Str2.replace("RV", "n"));
```

or if you want to do with char's only, you should try

```
        String replace = Str2.replace('R', 'n');
        replace = Str2.replace('V', 'n');
        System.out.println(replace);
```

And look at the replace signatures

```
replace(char oldChar, char newChar) 

replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
```

Both should be char's or String's. Can't alter them.